# Calculating elapsed time between two dates with times

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datediff, dataexplorer

I have created a function that takes 2 dates and returns descriptive duration like this:

1 Year 3 Months 2 Weeks 5 Days 10 Hours

The problem I am facing with this function is that if the duration is less than a month but if the two dates belong to different months, it returns month duration.

Can someone please help me tweak this function?

You can find the query here:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/149306

As you can see I am passing start date as `2013-08-29 13:48:35.710` and end date as `2013-09-03 17:04:27.493` and that should have returned the duration as `5 days 3 hours 15 minutes` but it returns 1 Month 3 Hours 15 minutes.

How do I tweak this in such a way that it displays the correct duration?

Comment: Determine the time difference in minutes (or hours) only and then use mathematics to calculate the rest (60 minutes per hour, 1440 minutes per day, 10080 minutes per week, etc.), subtracting from the total minutes as you go. You may need to consider leap-year too, but it is a viable and accurate option when done correctly.

Comment: Ugh, no.  4 months = how many hours? Use the built-in date manipulations instead of writing crappy ones that fail on DST, leap years, and leap seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @date1 DATETIME, @date2 DATETIME
DECLARE @result VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @years BIGINT, @months BIGINT, @weeks BIGINT, @days BIGINT, @hours BIGINT, @minutes BIGINT
DECLARE @KEEP DATETIME

SET @date1 = '20130829 13:48:35.710'
SET @date2 = '20130903 17:04:27.493'

if @date1>@date2 
begin
  SET @KEEP=@date1
  SET @date1=@date2
  SET @date2=@KEEP  
end

Select @years=DATEDIFF(yy,@date1,@date2)
if DateAdd(yy,-@years,@date2)<@date1 Select @years=@years-1
Set @date2= DateAdd(yy,-@years,@date2)

Select @months=DATEDIFF(mm,@date1,@date2)
if DateAdd(mm,-@months,@date2)<@date1 Select @months=@months-1
Set @date2= DateAdd(mm,-@months,@date2)

Select @weeks=DATEDIFF(wk,@date1,@date2)
if DateAdd(wk,-@weeks,@date2)<@date1 Select @weeks=@weeks-1
Set @date2= DateAdd(wk,-@weeks,@date2)        

Select @days=DATEDIFF(dd,@date1,@date2)
if DateAdd(dd,-@days,@date2)<@date1 Select @days=@days-1
Set @date2= DateAdd(dd,-@days,@date2)

Select @hours=DATEDIFF(hh,@date1,@date2)
if DateAdd(hh,-@hours,@date2)<@date1 Select @hours=@hours-1
Set @date2= DateAdd(hh,-@hours,@date2)

Select @minutes=DATEDIFF(mi,@date1,@date2)

Select @result= ISNULL(CAST(NULLIF(@years,0) as varchar(10)) + ' Years','')
     + ISNULL(' ' + CAST(NULLIF(@months,0) as varchar(10)) + ' Months','')
     + ISNULL(' ' + CAST(NULLIF(@weeks,0) as varchar(10)) + ' Weeks','')     
     + ISNULL(' ' + CAST(NULLIF(@days,0) as varchar(10)) + ' Days','')
     + ISNULL(' ' + CAST(NULLIF(@hours,0) as varchar(10)) + ' Hours','')
     + ISNULL(' ' + CAST(@minutes as varchar(10)) + ' Minutes','')

Select @result     

-- OUTPUT :  5 Days 3 Hours 16 Minutes
```

Comment: I love how you refactored the OP's code into a small, compact, working version :)

Comment: great solution but its missing weeks component. This is Not a complaint. :)